# How to get the RadioButtonlist selected value inside a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get the RadioButtonList selected value Behind the code so i can write the data in SQL database.
I am Creating the RadiobuttonList as many as question in Database table. Now i am facing difficulty how to get the answer(RadioButtonList value) for each Question(each row).

 How can i get he RadioButtonList value for each Dynamically created RadioButtonList.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterHeading1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SDSHeading">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="row">
       <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldHeadingId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Form_Heading_Id") %>' />
         <div class="col-md-12">
           <h4 class="h4" style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("Form_Heading_Name") %></h4>
         </div>
          <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterQuestion1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SDSQuestion">
             <ItemTemplate>
               <div class="col-lg-8">
                 <%# Eval("Form_Question") %>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4">
                   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"  DataSourceID="SDSRadio" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Remarks_Id" RepeatLayout="Flow" CellSpacing="10"></asp:RadioButtonList>
               </div>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
     </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to loop through the page and pick all the selected RadioButtonList value, store in a javascript array then post it to the server.
if you can make a sample of the generated html page available.. i can wipe up something efficient for you using javascript.